# How to reuse cells in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm running into some problems today in my application. I'm using a UITableView to present different cells some contain a specific button, some display a game your currently in, some are just for spacing between cells.

However im running into some problems when I do tableView.reloadData().

When I click on 'new game' a new game cell should be added, but instead of that the last cells are moved down (like expected, because something comes in between), however the upper cells that should change, they don't. I expect this to be because of reusing (or "**caching**"). Maybe someone can help me out on how to fix this.

**Here is an image of what is happening** [explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpzXH.png)

Now I have different cells, all with their own Identifiers for example: "Emptycell", "Gamecell", "startnewgameBtnCell". I do this because I create each cell in storybuilder.

here is my code for **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    let identifier = cell_identifiers[indexPath.row][0] as! String

    if ((cell_identifiers[indexPath.row][1] as! String) == "MYTURN" ) {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GameViewCell
        let match = self.myTurnMatches[indexPath.row - 4]
        setupGameViewCellObject(match)
    }

    if ((cell_identifiers[indexPath.row][1] as! String) == "NOT" ) {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FirstMenuTableViewCell
    }

    return cell
```

In this code I check if its a gamecell or not, emptycells or cells that contain a label or button are all FirstMenuTableViewCell. Only GameCell have their own class GameViewCell.

I have also double checked to see if my identifiers are build up correctly and they are.

Maybe someone can explain me exactly whats happening and what might be the correct approach to solve the situation I'm in, I think I may not fully understand how to use UITableViewCell with custom cells.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create new variables called cell in the if statements. You are hiding the outer cell.

Use one cell variable.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell

    let identifier = cell_identifiers[indexPath.row][0] as! String

    if ((cell_identifiers[indexPath.row][1] as! String) == "MYTURN" ) {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GameViewCell
        let match = self.myTurnMatches[indexPath.row - 4]
        setupGameViewCellObject(match)
    }

    if ((cell_identifiers[indexPath.row][1] as! String) == "NOT" ) {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FirstMenuTableViewCell
    }
    return cell 
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, what is the difference with my code? I don't see it.

Comment: u have 3 variable names cell, pointing to different objects. the cells in the if statements hide the outer one, that contains an empty cell, that you return. My code uses one variable.

Comment: Wow that fixed it, thank you. But I was always returning the correct cell right? How come this fixes it?

Comment: no, u where not returning the right cell, as the cells were only existent inside the scope of the i statements. you created and returned another cell object. You should never create a cell yourself, but dequeue it.

Comment: Thank you, I just spent 8 hours on this trying everything. you saved my night hehe! thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try update your code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = UITableViewCell()

let identifier = cell_identifiers[indexPath.row][0] as! String

if ((cell_identifiers[indexPath.row][1] as! String) == "MYTURN" ) {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GameViewCell
    let match = self.myTurnMatches[indexPath.row - 4]
    setupGameViewCellObject(match)
    return cell
}

if ((cell_identifiers[indexPath.row][1] as! String) == "NOT" ) {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FirstMenuTableViewCell
    return cell
}

return cell
```

if me, i coded:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = cell_identifiers[indexPath.row][0] as! String

    if ((cell_identifiers[indexPath.row][1] as! String) == "MYTURN" ) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GameViewCell
        let match = self.myTurnMatches[indexPath.row - 4]
        setupGameViewCellObject(match)
        return cell
    }else {  // if you sure just have 2 cell type
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FirstMenuTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

But i think you should use section in tableview,it is better. So, you have 3 section, and 2 headerofsection in there. the first section have 1 row, the second have self.myTurnMatches.count row.... :

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 0 || section == 1{
        return 44
    }else{
        return 0
    }
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 1{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GameViewCell 's identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GameViewCell
        let match = self.myTurnMatches[indexPath.row - 4]
        setupGameViewCellObject(match)
        return cell
    }else{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstMenuTableViewCell 's identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FirstMenuTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: The above answer was the solution. However I will consider using sections, thank you for your time.